# How can I loop through a list of times, find a skipped/missing time, then fill that time in?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, interpolation, missing-data

I have a list of files for every 12 minutes in a day. I should have 120 files, but I only have 114. This means there are 6, 12 minute periods of missing data/files. I created an array with datetimes on the left and my data on the right:

```
"row" -|-     "Time"       -|-       "Rain_Rate"      


1:    2014/04/02 00:00:09  |           0.5

2:    2014/04/02 00:12:20  |           1.1

3:    2014/04/02 00:24:05  |           0.48

4:    2014/04/02 00:36:51  |           2.3

5:    2014/04/02 01:00:08  |           4.1

6:    2014/04/02 01:12:26  |           5.0  

7:    2014/04/02 01:24:02  |           3.2
```

As you can see there is a missing time between row 4 and 5 (should be 00:48:00). How can I fill this row in by taking the average of the Rain_Rates from either side?

Also, how could I do this if there are 2 times/rows back to back missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, build an DateTimeIndex with 12 minute frequency:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 2)
end = datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 1)  # whenever your time series ends
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='12T')  # 12T = 12 minutes
```

Next, you have to build a dataframe with your new index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=idx, columns=['dummy']) # you need to provide a column name
```

I suppose, your Data is in a pd.Series `s` with a DateTimeIndex, otherwise you have to build one.

Now you can use the full power of DateTimeIndex and pandas:

```
df['Rain_Rate'] = s
df['Rain_Rate'] = df['Rain_Rate'].interpolate()  # standard is linear approximation
```

Check out [interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could keep your `Time` series as is, and only add rows into the missing positions you have describded, using the diffence in time between row been greater than 12min as the condition. As a trad-off depending on your previous existing values you won't get perfect 12min. time slices between the genereted row and the next existing value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
["2014/04/02 00:00:09",0.5],
["2014/04/02 00:12:20",1.1],
["2014/04/02 00:24:05",0.48],
["2014/04/02 00:36:51",2.3],
["2014/04/02 01:00:08",4.1],
["2014/04/02 01:12:26",5.0],
["2014/04/02 01:24:02",3.2],
["2014/04/02 02:44:02",1.2], # added for test
["2014/04/02 03:54:02",7.72] # added for test
])

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
print(df)

delta = df[0].diff()
diff_idx = delta.where(delta > pd.Timedelta("00:12:59"))
print(delta)
idx = df[diff_idx.notnull()].index

td = pd.Timedelta("00:12:00")

for k in idx:
    deltaT = (df.loc[k, 0] - df.loc[k - 1, 0])
    num_missrows =  deltaT // td
    num_missrows -= (-1, 0)[deltaT % td == pd.Timedelta(0)] # don't overlap last time value
    new_avg = df.loc[k - 1, 1]  # previous existing Rain value

    for i in range(1, num_missrows):
        avg = (df.loc[k, 1] + new_avg)/2
        new_row = [[df.loc[k-1, 0] + i * td, avg]]
        new_avg = avg
        df = df.append(new_row)

df = df.sort_values(by=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output from **df**

```
                     0        1
0  2014-04-02 00:00:09  0.50000
1  2014-04-02 00:12:20  1.10000
2  2014-04-02 00:24:05  0.48000
3  2014-04-02 00:36:51  2.30000
4  2014-04-02 00:48:51  3.20000 # added row
5  2014-04-02 01:00:08  4.10000
6  2014-04-02 01:12:26  5.00000
7  2014-04-02 01:24:02  3.20000
8  2014-04-02 01:36:02  2.20000 # added row
9  2014-04-02 01:48:02  1.70000 # added row
10 2014-04-02 02:00:02  1.45000 # added row
11 2014-04-02 02:12:02  1.32500 # added row
12 2014-04-02 02:24:02  1.26250 # added row
13 2014-04-02 02:36:02  1.23125 # added row, Not 12min. (~8min. diff.)
14 2014-04-02 02:44:02  1.20000
15 2014-04-02 02:56:02  4.46000 # added row
16 2014-04-02 03:08:02  6.09000 # added row
17 2014-04-02 03:20:02  6.90500 # added row
18 2014-04-02 03:32:02  7.31250 # added row
19 2014-04-02 03:44:02  7.51625 # added row, Not 12min. (~10min. diff.)
20 2014-04-02 03:54:02  7.72000
```